# Segmentation fault 11 when using matplotlib to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run a very simple python plot code (shown as follow), the segmentation fault 11 error comes out.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
```

It is quite weird. I run this code in mac terminal. The python is from Enthought canopy_64bit, version 2.7. The matplotlib's version is 1.5.0. The OX system is OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. Does someone know why is that?

Comment: What if you use ipython interactively? Open ipython, input line by line, then input `plt.show`.